# Is it possible to change screen backlight trough hardware means?

Tags: lcd, brightness, led, backlight, undervolting

Given that after several days I didn't manage to change the brightness through software means (askubuntu.com/questions/577539/dell-chromebook-11-unable-to-set-backlight-and-sys-class-backlight-empty and superuser.com/questions/868415/dell-chromebook-11-unable-to-set-backlight-and-sys-class-backlight-empty) I've come to a risk taking decision. I want to try lowering the backlight through hardware means.

Given that the level of backlight depends on how many volts power each pixel led I've thought with some hacking it should be possible to manually decrease the volts that power each pixel led maybe using some resistors on the LCD plate. Is something like that possible? If yes how? I'm ready to undertake this risky decision if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I'd suggest you keep looking for a software solution (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS works well on my netbook and controls all hardware; perhaps an Lubuntu update will fix the issue), here are some other options:

1. Electronics: Download the service manual for your chromebook, find out which pins power the LED (or cold-cathode fluorescent, on older machines) illumination, cut the *very* fine trace on the plastic flex cable, remove the surface insulation over the copper traces and solder in a resistor.
2. Optics: Find an anti-glare screen protector such as http://www.walmart.com/ip/Green-Onions-Supply-Anti-Glare-Screen-Protector-for-14.1-Inch-Laptop-LCD-screen-1-Piece-Transparent/14006131 or gray plastic sheet or film (e.g. https://www.interstateplastics.com/Pvc-Gray-Sheet-PVCGE__SH.php or http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Coated-anti-static-layer-protective-film_480490384.html [bulk]). Not optimal in that it wastes some current, but less likely to break the chromebook.

Comment: Thank you. I'd go with option 1 but before trying this risky operation I'm going to debug this chromebook to the barebone to find the culprit and solve it without drastic measures.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't do that, it's a horrible idea.** If you want your screen permanently darker through hardware then get a very dark [anti glare screen](http://www.officedepot.com/a/browse/antiglare-and-privacy-filters/N=5+590989/) overlay. Don't try to re-engineer your monitor unless you plan to never use it again.

Comment: Thanks! I'd avoid just putting an anti-glare screen because this little thing will overheat and draw too much power defeating what I bought it for: long battery life.